# jquery only fire if div#sidebar exists on page

Tags: jquery, scroll, target

I'm using the following code to control a div with the ID 'sidebar'

```
var top = $('#sidebar').offset().top - parseFloat($('#sidebar').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
            $(window).scroll(function (event) {
                // what the y position of the scroll is
                var y = $(this).scrollTop();

                // whether that's below the form
                if (y >= top) {
                  // if so, ad the fixed class
                  $('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
                } else {
                  // otherwise remove it
                  $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
                }
              });
```

However when a page that odes not contain div#sidebar it throws out an error stating #sidebar is null (because it's not there!)

How can I convert this code to only happen IF there is div#sidebar on the page?

Comment: Not really direct to the question, but you can replace the entire scroll content with this: `$('#sidebar').toggleClass('fixed', $(this).scrollTop() >= top);` :)

Comment: @Nick Thanks! Always nice to clean up code. This was actually from a tutorial I found here: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not wrong you can use

```
if ($('#sidebar').length > 0){

   .............

}
```

to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($('#sidebar').length > 0)
{
 //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce your code down using [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) to check if it exists and cache the selector, like this:

```
var sb = $('#sidebar');
if(sb.length) {
  var top = sb.offset().top - parseFloat(sb.css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    sb.toggleClass('fixed', $(this).scrollTop() >= top);
  });
}​
```

[`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) returns the number of elements the selector found, if it's not there it'll be `0` or `false` for the purposes of our `if()` check.  After that we're using [`.toggleClass(class, bool)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to more tersely add or remove the class based on the scroll positon.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
if($('#sidebar').size > 0){

//your code

}
```

Comment: `.size()` is a method...which really just calls `.length` :)